# Avg Total Percent Processor Time in System Center Operation Manager Reports

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, scom

In **system center 2012 operations manager** there is a report called **windows server operating system reports**. When I run the report there are two sections to do with the processor. One section is *"Processor - Average Total Percent Processor Time"* and the other is *"Processor Time - Average Total Percent Processor Time"* which confuses me.

Would someone be able to shed some light on the difference between these two?